# I can't set the variable in my class in swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
class Market {

    var  marketName: String? {
        get {
            return self.marketName
        }
        set {
            self.marketName = newValue
        }
    }

    var square: String? {
        get {
            return self.square
        }
        set {
            self.square = newValue
        }
    }

    init(marketName: String, square :String)
    {
        self.marketName = marketName
        self.square = square
    }
}
```

Why I can't initialize the variable Market? I have the warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available when it try to set the variables

Comment: there is not variable "`Market`"!

Comment: sorry, I can't declared a variable of Market type like this:
let auxMarket = Market(marketName: "market", square: "square")

Comment: Where, what is the exact error message, show that code.

Comment: I don't get any warnings for that code.

Comment: on "self.marketName = newValue" line I have "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xbf7f5ffc)"

Comment: Be aware that your code causes infinite loops – it will crash – in the setters by calling itself recursively. Explicit getters and setters are not needed anyway in this case.

Comment: @vadian your solution works!! Thank you